# How should one address people with titles Dr. and Professor?

Tags: titles, canada

How should one address people with titles Dr. and Professor from Canada.

Comment: Thhis has several answers: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/94091/72855

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an email write "Dear Prof. X". If you're addressing them in their role as a professor at the university that is the preferred form. If you're addressing them outside that role it seems to be equally common to use "Dear Dr. X".

Note, that unlike in some countries (like Germany) the form "Dear Prof. Dr. X" is not used in Canada.

Comment: I just realized that your "from Canada" has different possible interpretations. Do you mean they are now part of your local community after having moved from Canada or are you addressing someone who is from Canada and still in Canada? If it's the former, the other answer is correct. It's your local customs you should follow. If it's the latter I explain how to follow Canadian customs.

Answer (score -2):

Publicly, you should address them as you would their peers in your current country of residence. Privately, you can inquire as to their personal preference.

Comment: "You would do it like you would to anyone else" is not a very helpful response.

Comment: @AzorAhai There is distinct different between what I wrote and your interpretation. It appears that you have overlooked the word "peers".

Comment: Yes, you're right, I accidentally left off "anyone else with the same title." Your answer is still not helpful.

Comment: @AzorAhai I see no reason to distinguish between people on the basis of their country of origin. I look forward to learning why I am mistaken.